# Express WriteFile in GET Request without blocking response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, fs

I have a request that needs to be made upon app initialization in which part of the JSON response is parsed into JS and has to be written to a file – the rest of the response also needs to be received by the front end. Currently I have it setup like this:

```
function getAds(req, res) {
  console.log('GET Advertisements');
  let url = 'http://example.com/json/advertisements/v5/all';
  request(url, (err, response, body) => {
    let advertisements = JSON.parse(body);
    let script = advertisements.header;
    fs.writeFile('client/ads/dfpAds.js', script, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    });
    res.send(advertisements);
  });
}
```

This successfully writes to the JavaScript file, but it does not send the response to my front end *and* also blocks all other HTTP requests I'm making in other controllers.

Is it possible to do this? Do I need to separate the request that will handle the WriteFile and the other that will be sent to the front end?

I've tried a variety of combinations but I can never get the WriteFile to not block all other HTTP requests regardless. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: It shouldn't block. Are you sure that `res` is actually a valid response object? Are you using any middleware that may be processing responses?

Comment: If I remove the `fs.writeFile` portion of the function everything works, but then I'm not writing to the file – `res` is definitely a valid response object, not using any middleware that is processing this response.

Comment: The [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) states this: _"Note that it is unsafe to use `fs.writeFile` multiple times on the same file without waiting for the callback"_. So that might be the problem.

Comment: I'm only using it once though, not multiple times on the same file? Maybe I'm just not receiving any kind of callback, that would explain why all other asynchronous execution seems to be halted.

Comment: But it can get called multiple times, through different requests, can't it?

Comment: Actually I just discovered that Nodemon seems to be my problem – when the new file is written Nodemon restarts everything over again. If I just use Node it works fine.

Comment: Right, that would be a good reason...

Answer (score 0):

Add options parameter `{flag: 'w'}` works for me:

```
fs.writeFile('client/ads/dfpAds.js', script, {flag: 'w'}, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
});
```